# Network activity monitor for a specific process on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

I am looking for a programming solution for this problem, it can be win32 api, or other solution.
I have a process running on Windows, I have its PID.
I want to know what kind of multicast traffic it is doing, including receive and send.

I have searched from the web and found that:

- `wireshark`, cannot help me, because it cannot do process specific filter
- `netstat`, cannot help me, because it cannot show the multicast group, I did `netstat -aon`
- `network monitor`, cannot help me, it cannot show the process name when the traffic is multicast

`Process monitor` is an application which can almost do what I want, but the problem is it will output a very large log file, and I have to parse that file to find what I want.

Comment: Process Monitor allows you to apply an arbitrary set of filters, so the output is exactly, what you are looking for.

Comment: the problem is that when I am capturing events to file, there has no filter can be used. Also, it can only save the file as its default file type, and I have to use it to do the conversion back to `.csv` file /.\

Comment: There is an option to only capture the output that is defined by the filter. Menu "Filter" > "Drop Filtered Events". You can convert to CSV using following command-line: `procmon.exe /SaveAs <path>`. Type `procmon.exe /?` to see all parameters.

Comment: I have already using `Drop Filtered Events`, but there are still too many events /.\. `procmon.exe /SaveAs <path>` I have tried it before. This is no valid, this can be used only with /OpenLog, which means that I have to write the log file first then convert it to csv >.<

Comment: Btw, do you know how process monitor get the information about the process operation? If I can do that through windows api, then the problem may be solved @@"

Answer (score 0):

If it might help you,

Use Crowdinspect app[The screenshot of Crowdinspect running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY6Ew.png)

for your purpose just run the app then click "Live/History" button on the upper left corner so the app will start to show a history of your processes network activity and then you can click "Copy all" button then paste it in a text file or Excel sheet...

[ App Description ]

This app is used mainly for security purposes for detecting Maleware, it starts an analysis to all your processes and compare to Virus Total signatures and the possibility if the PE is injected with Malicious code.

Good Luck!

[Download Link](https://www.crowdstrike.com/resources/crowdinspect/)

Comment: Thank you very much but it is not what I want.

Comment: You are welcome, Have you tried [API Monitor] (rohitab.com/apimonitor) .. you can see that there is Networking Module in the left side and one of the tree view children of the module there is something about "Multicast" .. give it a try :)

Comment: That is very interesting, I will try it later @@" Thank you very much.